# Laravel - ajax creates double input

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have made this ajax request to show the validation errors and prevent the page to reload

```
$(document).on('mousedown', ':submit', function() {
    //alert('clicked submit');
    var form = $("form");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/events',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

        },
        error: function(data) {
            for(errors in data.responseJSON){
                swal({text:data.responseJSON[errors]});
            }
        }

    });
});
```

All is fine with this code! The problem is that after successfull submit i have 2 inputs in DB...how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the form isn't actually submitting and saving the values once by post and once by ajax? Usually if you're capturing a submit event you listen for the forms submit even not the mousedown event of the submit button e.g.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

    // Stop the forms default submit action
    e.preventDefault();

    //alert('clicked submit');
    var form = $("form");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/events',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

        },
        error: function(data) {
            for(errors in data.responseJSON){
                swal({text:data.responseJSON[errors]});
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Also the e.preventDefault() will prevent the form from submitting itself along with your ajax action. Also you'd best off selecting your form by an ID or class name.

Comment: I made this ajax only to prevent the page reload on errors...but if everything is fine then it should submit and save the input.....i have tried your code and now it creates the input but the page stays as it is....would location.reload(); solve my problem....i will try now

Comment: No location.reload(); inside success {} still stays on same page

Comment: But actually it refreshes behind the scenes in ajax response....oh man how to get this refresh in browser?

Comment: So the question is how to trigger the validation with ajax but without submitting the form...

Comment: My answer was wrong.....it doesn't work...i only had a error free form and it went through and because the validate() is not a jQuery native function it didn't serialize the form